# PHP session_start on xampp

Tags: php, windows, apache, session, xampp

Whenever i put session_start(); to my php code my site won't load anymore. I'm running xampp on windows server 2012. I tested same php code on my local machines xampp and it did work so I guess there is something wrong with my server. When I try to connect to my page I get following errors in apache error.log

> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:26.764131 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH00428: Parent: child process 2900 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:28.043237 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH01909: 192.168.0.14:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:28.323966 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:28.323966 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:28.323966 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d D:/XAMPP/apache'
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:28.323966 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3292
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:28.838770 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3292:tid 324] AH01909: 192.168.0.14:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:29.025972 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3292:tid 324] AH01909: 192.168.0.14:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:29.104269 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3292:tid 324] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:29.275575 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH00428: Parent: child process 3292 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:29.712379 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH01909: 192.168.0.14:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:29.759179 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:29.759179 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:29.759179 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d D:/XAMPP/apache'
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:29.759179 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1296:tid 412] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2964
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:30.211582 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2964:tid 328] AH01909: 192.168.0.14:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:30.383184 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2964:tid 328] AH01909: 192.168.0.14:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Thu Jan 28 13:20:30.414387 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2964:tid 328] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: the error says your "ssl" cert does not match server name

Comment: So how I can fix it?